# how to data table to order the column (bDestroy) and add Merge Cells function

Tags: jquery, merge, datatables

How to data table to order the column (bDestroy) add Merge Cells function

We append the table in ajax call

```
var oTable = $('#table').dataTable({     
   "bDestroy": true
   });
```

I use this code it not working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Whats the index of column in table? If its 3, then you should `"order": [[ 2, "desc" ]]` as its indexing is 0 based .

Comment: yes i know but nothing order in the table

Comment: Can you maybe add a snippet or jsfiddlet.net with dummy data so we can see where the issue is.

Comment: normal data-table is working it append ajax not working @designtocode